# Where I can find an USB dongle to connect two devices with external power?

Tags: usb

Can you please tell me where I can find an USB dongle which follows this diagram:

[image]

I have a tablet and a BobjGear USB to RJ45 Ethernet Adapter, but the battery will discharge while using the tablet connected to the network cable.

I want something as described in the diagram where A is the tablet, B is the Ethernet Adapter and C is the regular USB charger !

Does such a thing exists ?

What will happen to the tablet when I will try to provide the input power while it's supposed to be outputting power ? Is it even possible to connect the power in parallel - as the Tablet A is supposed to power the Adapter B ( **A -> B** )
Connecting the charger will force the current to flow in the opposite direction ( **C -> A** & **C -> B** ) ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the USB specification, these things *should NOT exist*. They are illegal (re: USB) for precisely the reasons you are struggling with it.

Electrically, we describe this condition as "contention." You are causing two power sources to fight for control of a wire. It's a bad thing... ;-)

USB On-The-Go (OTG) uses a separate pin (not shown in your diagram) to solve the contention issue.

Answer (score 0):

While that's essentially a `USB OTG y cable`, the problem is those cables are non-standard. ALSO, that most tablets, if not 99% of them, will not work that way even if the cables are connected like that. They will not charge while in USB-OTG mode, and at worst, can fry the tablet. The Galaxy Nexus Tablet, essentially the most open of Android tablets, needed 3rd party patches to allow that to work, and very very iffy at that.